# What is the literary device to describe isocolons with direct opposites?

Tags: antonyms, parallelism, figures-of-speech

In the poem 'We Shall Come No More' in Tawny Island by Verra Brittain, there is a strong parallelism between the 1st and 2nd stanza, even going as far as the same letter count. However the words are chosen to be opposite, or slightly contradictory. For example,
'So then we came to the Island,' is contrasted with 'To-day we look for the Island,' (Brittain went as far as using hyperbaton for exact parallelism perhaps?). This is slightly contradictory as you do not arrive somewhere, and then search for that somewhere.

Another example is the last line of the respective stanzas wherein 'Where shimmering lay the fields of Asphodel.' is contrasted with 'Where twilight falls on fields of Asphodel.' (only word count parallelism here by 1 letter). I was thinking of just calling it an antithetical isocolon or parallelism but I'm not sure whether there's a specific word for it.